# Suitable music festival where children can be taken (Big Chill replacement!)

Tags: safety, entertainment

I went to the Big Chill festival upto 2007 (a UK music festival in the Cotswolds) and have recently become a dad. The Big Chill was very child friendly and I would have loved to have taken my boy, but unfortunately that festival stopped in 2011.

Are there any purple people on here who could recommend an alternative for 2016? He'll be 1 year old.

Comment: I don't know what a purple person is?  Also, you might want to clarify a bit location and age(s) if you want a good answer.

Comment: @Joe: Wikipedia tells me "The Purple People (Italian: Il Popolo Viola) are an Italian mass protest movement who are calling for the resignation of Prime Minister Silvio Berlusconi" but I doubt that's what the OP is referring to :)

Comment: The only use of that phrase I'm familiar with are Minnesota Vikings fans, but also doubt that's relevant ;)

Comment: User's of the Big Chill Forum.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.telegraph.co.uk/lifestyle/10915407/Best-family-friendly-festivals.html

1. Latitude - July - Henham Park, Southwold, Suffolk.
2. Camp Bestival - July-August - Lulworth Castle, Dorset.
3. Womad - July - Charlton Park, Malmesbury, Wiltshire.
4. Green Man - August - Crickhowell, Brecon Beacons, Wales.
5. Just So - August - Rode Hall Parkland, Cheshire.

Answer (score 1):

From having played at many festivals, I can offer one amazing child friendly music festival, had and shoulders above the rest:

The Belladrum Tartan Heart Festival, held late summer up near Inverness

It is designed from the ground up to be family friendly, including child only areas, family and quiet camping, events and tuition for kids (including circus tuition) and my kids loved it at all ages.

Comment: Tuition in this context means 'classes'/teaching?

Comment: Yep - everything from unicycling and juggling to slack wire walking and fire breathing. (The last one was a joke :-)

Comment: Cool.  Tuition isn't used in American english that way - it means specifically the payment for classes - but it made sense in context.

Comment: Now that's something I never knew. Thanks.

Comment: I have a feeling it is officially "tuition payment" -> "payment for tuition [teaching/classes/learning]", but we just shortened it to "tuition" for some reason... too hard to say so many words for us I guess ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've not been myself but I know a few people with families who like to go to Shambala. It's free for under fives, has lots of activities for kids and a creche. Wikipedia also says it's family friendly. As I said I've not been so try to find out some more information first.